# How can I rotate a View by Y-axis in android?

Tags: android, animation, view, rotation

In my app, i would like rotate an `ImageView` by `setRotationY()`. In fact, it does. Just like from b to d, mirror effect and when i use `setRotation(45)` before `setRotationY()`, the result is that `setRotationY` is according to the device `Y-axis`, and i want the `rotationY` according to view self.

How? Can you guide me?
Thanks!

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: Not yet.... I use scale(0,-1) instead。。

Answer (score 21):

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
    animation.setDuration(3600);
    animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer,gabber. But setRotation before start animator,the result is not my expected。。

Comment: Thank you @Dmitriy . simple and best answer

Comment: Thanks, nice answer

Answer (score -1):

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 180, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotate.setDuration(5000);
rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

image.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Obviously, you could just put your imageView there