# android animation rotate an Image on itself

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I would like to make an animation in order to rotate an image on itself (by x pivot).

exactly like this : [image: coin who turn] [image: coin who turns]

I didn't find anything like that before and I already tried some tricks like :

```
public static void coinAnimation(final View v){
    RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(700);


    v.startAnimation(anim);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setAnimation(null);

        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430318/how-to-rotate-an-image-continuously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039658/how-can-i-rotate-a-view-by-y-axis-in-android)

Comment: These 2 animations are not like the gif I presented. @Zaki

Comment: These 2 animations are not like the gif I presented. @Kilarn123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, though it only works with 3.0 and above.

1) Create a new resources folder called "animator".

2) Create a new .xml file which I will call "flipping". Use the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="360" android:propertyName="rotationY" >
</objectAnimator>
```

No, the objectAnimator tags do not start with an uppercase "O".

3) Start the animation with the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext, R.animator.flipping); 
anim.setTarget(A View Object reference goes here i.e. ImageView);
anim.setDuration(3000);
anim.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Great Library with a bunch of animation.**

Try [YoYo](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) animation for any type of View.

Add below dependency in your application's build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.1'
        compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
        compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
}
```

**Example:**

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.FlipOutY)
.duration(700)
.repeat(5)   // If you want to do INFINITELY then set "-1" value here
.playOn(findViewById(R.id.edit_area));
```

Comment: I tried it but the coin only turn half start to disappeared then restart from the beginning